# Same Storyboard animation for multiple elements

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I recently started studying C# wpf. I want to know can we use same storyboard for multiple targets. I know this can be achieved with XAML but i don't know how to achieve it through c# code. I am doing something like when storyboard begins the animation then for 0-2sec one element completes animation and then from 2-4 sec duration another element does its animation. In this way the total duration of storyboard is 4 seconds.
Below is the XAML code i found on the web, I want to do something like this in c# code

```
<Storyboard x:Name=”sbFlip“> 
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime=”00:00:00” Storyboard.TargetName=”front”  Storyboard.TargetProperty=”(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)“> 
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime=”00:00:00.2” Value=”0“/> 
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime=”00:00:00.2” Storyboard.TargetName=”back” Storyboard.TargetProperty=”(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)“> 
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime=”00:00:00.4” Value=”1“/> 
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames> 
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let These are the three objects in the View:

```
  <Rectangle x:Name="rctMovingObject1" Fill="LimeGreen" Width="50" Height="50"/>
  <Rectangle x:Name="rctMovingObject2" Fill="Red" Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Top="136"/>
  <Rectangle x:Name="rctMovingObject3" Fill="Purple" Width="50" Height="50" Canvas.Top="69"/>
```

You can define an animation from back-end and assign to all of them as follows:

```
var anim = new DoubleAnimation
  {
     From = 1920,
     To = 1,
     Duration =new Duration(new TimeSpan(0,0,2))// a duration of 2 seconds 
  };
rctMovingObject1.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, anim);
rctMovingObject2.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, anim);
rctMovingObject3.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, anim);
```

[Read More...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: How the time is being divided here? And isn't the storyboard necessary? thanks in advance

Comment: you can add duration `Duration =new Duration(new TimeSpan(0,0,2))`

Comment: Ahhh.. nice, and what about the storyboard? When its necessary?